# Cesaro convergence

Tags: calculus, limits

Suppose we are given a sequence $(a_n)_n$ such that $0\leq a_n\leq 1$ for all $n$ and $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N a_n\to a$ as $N\to\infty$. Does this imply
$$
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^Na_n^2\to a^2\;?
$$

Comment: More or less like asking if $\mathbb{E}[X]=a$ implies $\mathbb{E}[X^2]=a^2$. Well, no. Actually by Jensen's inequality $\mathbb{E}[X^2]\geq\mathbb{E}[X]^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Consider the sequence $1,0,1,0,1,0,\dots$. Then $a_n=a_n^2$ and both Cesaro menas converge to $1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by Stolz-Cesàro theorem, $\lim (\frac{\sum^N a^2_{n}}{N}) = \lim a_{n+1}^2$ which in turn is equal to $\lim^2 a_{n+1}$ and by your hypothesis to $a^2$.

Comment: there is no reason why $\lim a_n$ should exist.